# OAuth2 spring security server - not found (using Credentials flow)

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to understand how OAuth 2 Client Credentials Flow works

```java
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {


    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("secret") //clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }


}
```

```xml
 <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

An example that I found It offers pass to reference http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/token

but in response comes : NOT FOUND.

I had to get an access token. can anyone share knowledge on how to set up this process (when one application receives an access token and through it comes to the resource server).

But in my case (I use Postman), I can't see the token at the above address.